# waitForConfirmsOrDie vs PublisherCallbackChannel.Listener

Tags: spring-amqp

I need to achieve the impact of waitForConfirmsOrDie in core java implementation in spring . In core java it is achievable request wise ( channel.confirmSelect , set Mandatory , publish and Channel.waitForConfirmsOrDie(10000) will wait for 10 sec)

I implemented template.setConfirmCallback ( hope it is same as  PublisherCallbackChannel.Listener) and it works great , but  ack/nack  is at a common place ( confirm call back ) ,  for the individual sender no  idea like waitForConfirmsOrDie , where he is sure within this time ack hasn't came and can take action

do send methods wait for specified period internally  like waitForConfirmsOrDie in spring if ack hasn't came and if publisherConfirms is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no equivalent of `waitForConfirmsOrDie` in the Spring API.

Using a connection factory with publisher confirms enabled calls `confirmSelect()` on its channels; together with a template confirm callback, you can achieve the same functionality by keeping a count of sends yourself and adding a method to your callback to wait - something like...

```
@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate template;

private void runDemo() throws Exception {
    MyCallback confirmCallback = new MyCallback();
    this.template.setConfirmCallback(confirmCallback);
    this.template.setMandatory(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        template.convertAndSend(queue().getName(), "foo");
    }
    confirmCallback.waitForConfirmsOrDie(10, 10_000);
    System.out.println("All ack'd");
}

private static class MyCallback implements ConfirmCallback {

    private final BlockingQueue<Boolean> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    @Override
    public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause) {
        queue.add(ack);
    }

    public void waitForConfirmsOrDie(int count, long timeout) throws Exception {
        int remaining = count;
        while (remaining-- > 0) {
            Boolean ack = queue.poll(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (ack == null) {
                throw new TimeoutException("timed out waiting for acks");
            }
            else if (!ack) {
                System.err.println("Received a nack");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

One difference, though is the channel won't be force-closed.

Also, in a multi-threaded environment, you either need a dedicated template/callback per thread, or use `CorrelationData` to correlate the acks to the sends (e.g. put the thread id into the correlation data and use it in the callback).

I have opened [AMQP-717](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-717) for us to consider providing something like this out of the box.